# Small, Power-Efficient wireless communication with ATTiny85

Tags: arduino-uno, attiny

For a project that I'm working on I need an extremely small, power efficient wireless device (could be radio, or some other interface) to network between a series of ATTiny85s and a larger Arduino. The communication range only needs to be about 1 foot, max. I'm currently using wired I2C, so it would be excellent if someone could suggest a radio or another device that can use the two digital pins previously occupied by the SCK and SDA lines on the ATTiny. I have those two, along with one extra digital pin available for use.

This device needs to be extremely small - [this common NRF24L01](http://www.miniinthebox.com/upgraded-2-4ghz-nrf24l01-wireless-transceiver-module-for-arduino-black_p683437.html) package is too big and its SPI interface uses too many pins.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are ways to interface with a NRF24L01 with ATTiny85 with reduced pin usage plus you could use a ceramic antenna and cut off the large SPI header. It is possible to turn a NRF24L01 really small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An RF kit like [this one](http://www.elecfreaks.com/estore/315mhz-rf-link-kit.html). It's a 2-part kit, Tx and Rx separately -- each needing Vcc, GND and one pin. You need both on each ATTiny to be able to transmit and receive.

Comment: A similar product but a lot smaller would be the [SYN115 and SYN480R based modules](http://www.ebay.com/itm/433MHZ-Transmitter-Receiver-Module-SYN115-SYN480R-ASK-Wireless-Module-/351350062982). These are however dumb devices, so you need to implement a protocol for them, and handle/prevent collisions, have some data integrity protection, etc.

Comment: Definitely. And that will eat up precious memory -- more code...

Comment: Link is dead.  Instead of saying something "this one" can you give a model number that can be searched?

Answer (score 4):

I've also had good results with using the [Mchr3k - Arduino Manchester Encoding](https://mchr3k.github.io/arduino-libs-manchester/) library with those 315mhz RF kits. It has support for ATTiny85 as well.